# List of EOS accounts who are staking my account's CPU and/or NET bandwidth

Tags: eos

is there a way to determine exactly what accounts have staked EOS to my contract, and the amount of EOS each such staker has staked to CPU and NET?

I know that the `cleos` command

```
$ cleos system listbw <my-contract-account>
```

will list the accounts which `my-contract-account` has staked; I'm looking for the reverse of this: given a contract, who out there in the wild world of EOS has staked me?

Answer (score 0):

Use EOSPark, look under "stake detail"->"staked by others". This option can be found below the token listings.